# Is there a way to reference a local variable within a Rust macro?

Tags: rust, macros

I would like to use macros to generate the body of a function, but to do so they need to access variables in the local scope:

```rust
macro_rules! generate_func {
    ($name:ident) => {
        fn $name(param: i32) {
            generate_body!()
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! generate_body {
    () => {
        println!("{}", &param);
    }
}

generate_func!(foo);
```

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `param` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:11:25
   |
11 |         println!("{}", &param);
   |                         ^^^^^ not found in this scope
...
15 | generate_func!(foo);
   | -------------------- in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0341ce89736b620af9143a4e3d41a5a4)

It's very frustrating that this doesn't work, because I can run `cargo-expand` and see that the resulting code is valid:

```rust
fn foo(param: i32) {

    {
        ::std::io::_print(::core::fmt::Arguments::new_v1(&["", "\n"],
                                                         &match (&&param,) {
                                                              (arg0,) =>
                                                              [::core::fmt::ArgumentV1::new(arg0,
                                                                                            ::core::fmt::Display::fmt)],
                                                          }));
    }
}
```

(this is a bit messy because of the `println!`, but you can see the valid reference there)

I can even copy and paste the expansion into my source and the compiler accepts it. Surely there is some way to accomplish the desired outcome?

It seems roughly related to:

- ["cannot find value `a` in this scope" in Rust macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804878/cannot-find-value-a-in-this-scope-in-rust-macro)
- https://github.com/dtolnay/proc-macro-hack/issues/15

But I couldn't be sure that I had the exact same issue; my case seems more basic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rust macros are [hygienic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro), which prevents identifiers from one scope leaking into another and causing all manner of mayhem.  But you can solve this particular problem by passing `param` from `generate_func` to `generate_body`:

```
macro_rules! generate_func {
    ($name:ident) => {
        fn $name(param: i32) {
            generate_body!(param)
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! generate_body {
    ($param:ident) => {
        println!("{}", &$param);
    }
}

generate_func!(foo);
```

See it on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=345b2bee27cd249e7f27b67905dcbc48).